# How do we do the API vertical slicing?

Tags: api

I want to understand how do we vertical slice an API. Since API is a single component for which we can apply the INVEST criteria. I want to understand if there is a way to do a vertical slicing for an API.

Comment: What do you mean by "an API is a single component"? An API can have many parts and you can vertically slice it like any other type of software. Can you go into more detail what your problem is with doing it?

Comment: You need to explain why you and your team think an API is a single unit that can't be decomposed. Without that information, we can't address the X in is likely an X/Y problem based on a fundamental misunderstanding that might be easy to correct if we knew what it was.